# Joomla Insert Media form element via ajax

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I am building a custom Joomla 3.0 administrator component and part of it requires some ajax calls to insert various types of fields.

I have been unable to insert a Media field though.

For the regular inputs I've just created the html directly.
For the editor I've used the following code (I've just pasted an extract):

```
$editor = JFactory::getEditor();
$html .= $editor->display($name, $value, '100%', '250px', 20, 20, true, $id);
echo $html;
```

I would prefer not to recreate the html code for the Media field as there is a fair amount of html and javascript which could potentially change in future versions of Joomla.  Is there a method similar to the JFactory:getEditor() I could use?

I've also tried creating an instance of the Media class but it requires a form object which I don't think is accessible (or at least I don't know how to fetch it) when doing the ajax call.

```
$xml = '<field
    name="test"
    type="media"                        
/>';
$field = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$media = new JFormFieldMedia();
$media->setup($field,'');

echo $media->input;
```

Comment: It seems to me that the biggest issue is that the media field adds a script declaration to the document via `JFactory::getDocument()->addScriptDeclaration` and the `modal` behavior. This makes loading it asynchronously rather problematic. Why not load a media field and hide it until required? Or do you want several of them loaded on demand and do not know the number of needed fields at the time the page is generated?

Comment: Unfortunately it's a case of not knowing the number of needed fields.  Essentially I have custom fields that can be created and applied to the main model, these fields are only loaded when the user specifies which "group" of custom fields to load, hence the reason I cannot determine how many.  My fallback will be to create the html in my own image field but it means that it will not be updated automatically with newer versions of joomla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out how to add the media element.  It's not the exact same input selection so I built my own, for calling the image selector I was able to do it by calling it via javascript with this function:

```
SqueezeBox.open('index.php?option=com_media&view=images&tmpl=component&asset=com_mycomponent&author=&fieldid=gallery_result' + field_id + '&folder=gallery',
            {
                size:
                        {
                            x: 800,
                            y: 500
                        },
                handler: 'iframe'
            }
    )
```

Still not perfectly what I was looking for, but close enough.

Answer (score 1):

There is an Extension for K2 that does video called JW ALL VIDEOS. It's free, I recommend you download it and take a look how it's being done there for study purposes:

http://www.joomlaworks.net/extensions/free-premium/allvideos

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I have gone through the extension but it does not appear to do what I am attempting.  It is a plugin for content, not a component and it does not have any ajax calls to pull a media element into the form.